# Only replace own website url in text with HTML links

Tags: php

When user post a comment, i strip all the html tags in the comment before insert into my database because i do not want them to post external links(SPAM) in the comment. But i only want to strip external links, i want to display my own website URL as normal clickable links. How to detect the URL is my own website's URL and make it clickable as usual?

Example in the comment:
Blah... blah... blah... http://my_website_url.com Blah... blah... blah... Blah... blah... blah... Blah... blah... blah... Blah... blah... blah... Blah... blah... blah...http://external_links.com Blah... blah... blah... Blah... blah... blah...

As above example, i want ONLY http://my_website_url.com become clickable link before insert into my database. (http://my_website_url.com to < a href="http://my_website_url.com" >http://my_website_url.com< /a > )

Also, not only detect the main URL:http://my_website_url.com, but also:

-http://www.my_website_url.com

-www.my_website_url.com

-my_website_url.com

-http://my_website_url.com/blah/blah/blah

-http://www.my_website_url.com/blah/blah/blah

-www.my_website_url.com/blah/blah/blah

-my_website_url.com/blah/blah/blah

or any URLs that from my website:http://www.my_website_url.com/xxx/xxx/xxx/xxx

If could, please post exactly php codes to let me copy and paste into my file because i have little knowledge with php only. Thanks guys. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I wrote a function for it:

```
function makeSiteClickable($dom, $website = 'my_website_url.com')
{
    $words = explode(' ', $dom);
    foreach($words as &$word){
        if(strpos($word, $website) == true){
            // there you can make some sterilizing
            $href = str_replace('http://', '', $word);
            $href = str_replace('www.', '', $href);
            $word = '<a href="http://'.urlencode($href).'">'.$word.'</a>';
        }
    }

    return implode(' ', $words);
}
```

Comment: Thanks seferov, but the code is not work if there is a comma or line break after the word. Example:

This is a test: my_website_url.com, and blah blah blah...
as above example, it will echo: < a href="my_website_url.com,">my_website_url.com,< /a> or if there is line break after the my_website_url.com, it will echo: < a href="my_website_url.com<br><br>this">my_website_url.com<br><br>this< /a>.

Comment: I just give the basic structure of code. You may such characters to an array and explode the whole file accordingly